# What should I know before reading Ordinary Differential Equations of VI Arnold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

I have just adquired some math books and VI Arnold is one of them. But it was more sophisticated that I may think, so I want to know what should I know to be able to read it. Actually I have on my belt, linear algebra and calculus of one variable. Can somebody help me?

Comment: You don't need anything beside a passion for learning.